# SQL: Return first instance of an access request

Tags: sql, select

I rarely use SQL and I'm having trouble with this task.
This table has all the information I need.

A person can request access to a sector of a building, and for that 2 types of approbations may be needed.

I have to discover the data about the first request a user did for each building it has access

If user Jon requested access to sector "A" and 2 weeks later for sector "B", I just have to return the information about 
who approved sector's "A" and when.

I can find out the which sector was requested first and the date. But I don't know how to return the approvers since they are in another 
row. I think the key here is to use the ticket number.

**Records**

```
ID  EVENTDATE   TICKET  USER    ACTION  EVENT   APPROVER    BUILDING    SECTOR  STATUS
15  7/1/2015 12:25  17C9F862    4003321 New access request  Started -   OHIO    IT_2    Running
14  7/1/2015 12:41  17C9F862    4003321 Approved    Manager approval    4001719 OHIO    IT_2    Running
12  7/1/2015 15:29  17C9F862    4003321 -   Finished    -   OHIO    IT_2    Finished: Approved
13  7/1/2015 15:29  17C9F862    4003321 Approved    Director Approval   4003468 OHIO    IT_2    Running
10  7/1/2015 20:57  897B9A0A    4003321 New access request  Started -   OHIO    DEVELOPMENT Running
11  7/1/2015 20:57  F3DCFB96    4003321 New access request  Started -   OHIO    INFRA_2 Running
9   7/1/2015 20:58  897B9A0A    4003321 Approved    Manager approval    4001719 OHIO    DEVELOPMENT Running
8   7/1/2015 20:58  F3DCFB96    4003321 Approved    Manager approval    4001719 OHIO    INFRA_2 Running
7   7/1/2015 21:01  F3DCFB96    4003321 Approved    Director Approval   4001547 OHIO    INFRA_2 Running
6   7/1/2015 21:01  F3DCFB96    4003321 -   Finished    -   OHIO    INFRA_2 Finished: Approved
4   7/1/2015 21:03  897B9A0A    4003321 -   Finished    -   OHIO    DEVELOPMENT Finished: Approved
5   7/1/2015 21:03  897B9A0A    4003321 Approved    Director Approval   4001549 OHIO    DEVELOPMENT Running
3   7/1/2015 21:22  3E18483E    4003321 Approval not needed Finished    -   OHIO    IT_1    Finished: Approved
2   7/2/2015 9:48   F902EB9C    4003321 Approval not needed Finished    -   UTAH    FINANCE Finished: Approved
1   7/2/2015 11:08  C186101C    4003321 Approval not needed Finished    -   OHIO    INFRA_1 Finished: Approved
```

**Desired Result:**

```
USER    Manager Approver    Director Approver   BUILDING    SECTOR  DATE
4003321 4001719 4003468 OHIO    IT_2    7/1/2015 15:29
4003321 -   -   UTAH    FINANCE 7/2/2015 9:48
```

**SQL used**

```
SELECT SEL.USER
     , SEL.BUILDING
     , SEL.SECTOR
     , SEL.EVENTDATE
     , SEL.TICKET 
FROM ACCESSREQUESTS SEL 
INNER JOIN 
         (
          SELECT USER
               , BUILDING
               , SECTOR
               , MIN(EVENTDATE) as data 
         FROM ACCESSREQUESTS 
         WHERE EVENT = 'Finished' 
           AND STATUS = 'Finished: Approved' 
           AND USER != 'null' 
         GROUP BY USER
                , BUILDING
                , SECTOR 
         ORDER BY USER
        ) RE ON RE.DATA = SEL.EVENTDATE 
            AND SEL.STATUS = 'Finished: Approved'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I couldn't really tell from your sample data where one column's data ended and the next one started so I may have some columns wrong, but try adding in this:

```
left join (select 
    ticket
    , approver 
from accessrequests 
where event = 'Approved  Director Approval') as Director_Approval 
on Director_Approval.ticket = sel.ticket

left join (select 
    ticket
    , approver 
from accessrequests 
where event = 'Approved  Manager Approval') as Manager_Approval 
on Manager_Approval.ticket = sel.ticket
```

Then in your select add just add in

```
isnull(Manager_approval.approver,'') as Manager_approver,
isnull(Director_approval.approver,'') as director_approver
```

You may need to tack it into your subquery there, but that should hopefully point you in the right direction :)